# modify variable in argument of conditional python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a while loop that operates on outputs provided by another class, until no outputs are left.

```
while a.is_next():
   fn(a.get_next())
```

Is there a way of checking if a new item exists and. "loading" it at the same time?

```
while b=a.get_next():
  fn(b)
```

Comment: This feature is (controversially) [planned for Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to reinvent the [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).  Iterators must have two methods: an `__iter__` method that returns the iterator itself and a `__next__` method that returns either the next item or raises `StopIteration`.  For example

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [1, 2, 3]
        self.index = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            ret = self.list[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return ret
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
```

That's a lot for that example, but it allows us to use that iterator everywhere Python expects an iterator

```
for x in MyIterator():
    print(x)

1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want this but you can assign and check if exists in the same statement like:

```
import itertools as it
for b in (x.get_next() for x in it.repeat(a) if x.is_next()):
    fn(b)
```

Comment: Huh, for some weird reason I didn't think of using a for-loop. Good idea. +1. My only objection would be that this is a little sore on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of checking if a new item exists and. "loading" it at the same time?

The short answer is no. Python assignments cannot be done in the place of a `while` loop's conditional statement. However, why not simply reassign the value of `a.get_next()` to a variable each iteration, and use that as your loops conditional:

```
b = a.get_next() # get the initial value of b
while b:
    fn(b)
    b = a.get_next() # get the next value for b. If b is 'fasly', the loop will end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for generators, iterators and yield statement.

Code example

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self,l):
        self.l = l
    def next(self):
        i = 0
        while (i < len(self.l)):
            yield self.l[i]
            i += 1

c = Container([1,2,3,4,5])


for item in c.next():
    print(item, end=" ") # 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: ... why not use the iterator protocol?